# why $F(g(a)) \subset F(a)?$

Tags: field-theory

Let $f(x)$ a irreducible polynomial of degree $n$ over a field $F$. Let $g(x)$ be a polynomial in $F[x]$. Prove that every irreducible factor of the composition $f(g(x))$ has a degree which is divisible by $n$.

**My attempt** : I got the answer  [here](https://positron0802.wordpress.com/algebra-dummit-chapter-13-solution/)  .But  I have some confusion

my confusion is given below  marked in red box

[image]

**My confusion**:  why  $F(g(a)) \subset F(a)?$

Here   $a  \subset g(a)   $ so i think $F(a) \subset F(g(a))$?

Comment: Isn't $g(a)\in F(a)$ since $g(a) $ is a polynomial in terms of $a$, and so $F(g(a))\subset F(a)$?

Comment: When $\beta$ is algebraic over $F$, $F(\beta)$ is the set of things of the form 

$$a_0 + a_1 \beta + a_2 \beta^2 + \operatorname{etc.}$$
where $a_i \in F$, so this is obvious.

Comment: @chhro you  mean $a \notin F(a)$  but $g(a) \in F(a)?$

Comment: @D_S but $F(g(a))$ is als0 of  the form $a_0+a_1 g(a) + a_2 g(a)^2+.........$i don't see  any difference

Comment: $a$ is an element of the field $F(a)$, right?  $g(a)$ is an element of the field $F(a)$, right?  So what are you confused on?

Comment: got  its  and thanks you  for answer @D_S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you wrote, "$a \subset g(a)$," does not make sense.  $a$ and $g(a)$ are elements, not sets.

We have $g(a) = c_0 + c_1a + \cdots + c_na^n$ for some $c_i \in F$.  Since $a$ is an element of the field $F(a)$, and $F(a)$ is closed under addition and multiplication, this implies that $g(a)$ is also an element of $F(a)$.

Therefore every element of the form $cg(a)^n$ for $c \in F$ and $n \geq 0$ is in $F(a)$.  Therefore, the field $F(g(a))$ is contained in $F(a)$.